# Finding all the subsets that sum n via backtracking

Tags: java, backtracking

I want to find all the integer subsets that sum n via backtracking

For example for the integers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and n = 7

I want to ouput

```
1 2 4
1 6
2 5
3 4
7
```

I think that I should pass the position in the integer array that I'm evaluating as argument, but I'm stuck writing the rest of the logic.

My code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author talleres
 */
public class Main {




int sum (TreeSet<Integer>ts, int temp) {

    int sum=0;

    for (Integer i: ts){

        sum +=i;

    }

    return sum+temp;
}



static HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>> alternatives = new HashSet <TreeSet<Integer>>();
static ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList <TreeSet<Integer>>();

static TreeSet<Integer> getNextSubset (){

    TreeSet<Integer> alternative = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    if (!alternatives.contains(alternative)){   
        return alternative;   
    }
    else return null; // BEWARE!! 
} 

static void findSubsets (ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int amount, int index){


    TreeSet <Integer> subset = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    int temp = numbers.get(index); //initialize alternative

    if (temp<=amount)
        subset.add(temp);

    if (temp==amount)
        subsets.add(subset);




}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("inset integers");

        ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line=br.readLine();

        while (!line.equals("")){
            numeros.add (Integer.parseInt(line));
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        Collections.sort(numeros);

        System.out.println("insert the amount the subsets should sum");
           line = br.readLine();

        int amount = Integer.parseInt(line);

        ArrayList<Integer> accum = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        findSubsets(numeros, amount, 0);


    }

}
```

Comment: What can we help you on?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudo code for you to work with:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> subsets(Set<Integer> remaining, int n) {
    results = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

    if (n == 0)
        results.add(empty set);

    for each i in remaining
        newRemaining = remaining \ {i}

        for each subresult in subsets(newRemaining, n - i)
            results.add(subresult + {i})

    return results
}
```

Should work for negative numbers as well. (uhm, actually *will* work. I implemented it and tested it before writing the pseudo code :-)

Comment: Set<Set<Integer>> subsets(Set<Integer> remaining, int n) {
   HashSet<Set<Integer>> results = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

    if (n == 0)
        results.add(new TreeSet<Integer>());

   
   for (Integer i:remaining){
   
      Set<Integer> newRemaining = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        newRemaining.remove(i);
        
        for (Set<Integer> subresult: subsets){
        
            results.add(subresult.add(i));
        
        }
   
   
   }

Comment: and getting a "cannot find symbol" error on line results.add(subresult.add(i));

Comment: `subresult.add(i)` returns a boolean. split it up into two lines.

Comment: how did you implement this line? for each subresult in subsets(newRemaining, n - i)
            results.add(subresult + {i})

Comment: post your entire code at pastebin and provide me with a link.

Comment: You're still doing `set.add(blah.add(i))` which doesn't make sense. try something like this: http://pastebin.com/R9bf3u9a

Comment: Sorry, did I really paste that? I had already made that change. I think I controlled-Z the mod. The problem is the for-each is being called on a *data structure* subsets not the method subsets.

Comment: You really have to create a *new* set for each `newSubResult`. See my pastebin-post.

Answer (score 1):

I might be tempted to do this in a recursive function.  It feels straightforward.  It might not be the best, but it will work well.

This is very much in pseudo-code and assumes the numbers are 1..END.  If you are given a list, sorting and then using list[i] would be appropriate.

```
find(int curpos,int cursum,int sumleft,char output[])
{
  if (sumleft == 0)
   print(output);
  if (curpos > sumleft)
   return;
  for(i=curpos;i<=TARGET && i<=sumleft)
    find(i+1,cursum+i,sumleft-i,output+i."+%d")
}

main()
{
  char output[100];
  find(1,0,TARGET,"");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, since the question asked for backtracking... but +1 because it's exactly what I thought of when I read the question, and it never hurts to point out other solutions to a problem.