# 4sum implementation in Java from leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem statement from leetcode says:

> Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c, and d in S such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.

Note:

```
Elements in a quadruplet (a,b,c,d) must be in non-descending order. (ie, a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d)
The solution set must not contain duplicate quadruplets.
```

About this four sum problem, I have 2 questions:

1. Where I went wrong? The compiled code cannot pass all the tests, but I thought the code should be right since it is only using brute force to solve the problem.
2. Is there any efficient way to solve the four sum problem instead of this O(n^4) run-time algorithm?

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FourSumSolution{
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fourSum(int[] num, int target){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int N = num.length;

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++)
                for(int k=j+1; k<N; k++)
                    for(int l=k+1; l<N; l++){
                        int sum = num[i] + num[j] + num[k] + num[l];                        
                        if(sum == target){
                            ArrayList<Integer> tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            Collections.addAll(tempArray, num[i], num[j], num[k], num[l]);
                            aList.add(tempArray);
                        }
                    }
        return aList;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit more on what the original problem is, some people might think four sum refers to something else...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139093/finding-all-the-subsets-that-sum-n-via-backtracking

Comment: You need to provide a link to the problem.

Comment: To Gene and Dann.dev, Thanks a lot. I edited the post, and the link is http://www.leetcode.com/onlinejudge. The problem is 4sum. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an O(n^3) solution

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
public class Solution {
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fourSum(int[] num, int target) {
    // Start typing your Java solution below
    // DO NOT write main() function

    Arrays.sort(num);
    HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hSet = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1, l = num.length - 1; k < l;) {
                int sum = num[i] + num[j] + num[k] + num[l];
                if (sum > target) {
                    l--;
                }
                else if (sum < target) {
                    k++;
                }
                else if (sum == target) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> found = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    found.add(num[i]);
                    found.add(num[j]);
                    found.add(num[k]);
                    found.add(num[l]);
                    if (!hSet.contains(found)) {
                        hSet.add(found);
                        result.add(found);
                    }

                    k++;
                    l--;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does not use hash. It should be faster, but it still exceeds the time limit.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[] S = {1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 2};
      int target = 0;
      test(S, target);
    }

    public static void test(int[] num, int target) {
      System.out.print("a:");
      for (int i : num) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
      }
      System.out.println(": " + target);
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = fourSum(num, target);
      for (ArrayList<Integer> list : res) {
        System.out.println(list);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    // a+b+c+d = target
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fourSum(int[] num, int target) {
        // Start typing your Java solution below
        // DO NOT write main() function

       // Sort
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) {
                if (num[j] < num[i]) {
                    int tmp = num[i];
                    num[i] = num[j];
                    num[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
       }
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
      int i = 0;
      while (i < num.length - 3) {
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < num.length - 2) {
            int k = j + 1, l = num.length - 1;
            while (k < l) {
                int sum = num[i] + num[j] + num[k] + num[l];
                if (sum > target) {
                    l--;
                    while (k < l && num[l] == num[l+1]) l--;
                } else if (sum < target) {
                    k++;
                    while (k < l && num[k] == num[k-1]) k++;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Integer> list =
                        new ArrayList<Integer>(4);
                    list.add(num[i]); list.add(num[j]);
                    list.add(num[k]); list.add(num[l]);
                    res.add(list);
                    k++;
                    while (k < l && num[k] == num[k-1]) k++;
                    l--;
                    while (k < l && num[l] == num[l+1]) l--;
                }
            }
            j++;
            while (j < num.length && num[j] == num[j-1]) j++;
        }
        i++;
        while (i < num.length && num[i] == num[i-1]) {
            i++;
        }
      }

      return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You solution is obviously calculating correctly. But if a value appears several times in the input array there will be given "same" results. Maybe that was tested.

The "twoSum" of num = { 1, 3, 1, 3, 4 } with target = 4 would be:

- { 1, 3 }
- { 1, 3 }
- { 3, 1 }
- { 1, 3 }

It this was the reason for failing in tests, the solution would probably be **a set of an ordered list**.

If also subsets must be given, { 4 } is missing.

*So the question is, why did the tests fail, what are the requirements.*

An optimisation probably involves special data structures: at least a (reverse) sorted num.
Many links are already given. Recursion can help to find an **provable** and understandable optimal solution, with pre and post conditions. (As you are splitting the problem.)

One solution would be be creating pairs keeping a mapping of pair sum to all pairs of indices leading to that sum. And then find two pairs with disjunct indices.

---

***As no one gave a satisfactory answer:***

A simple recursive solution (not very nice or optimal). However it demonstrates that data structures are relevant.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class FourSumSolution {

    private static class SortedTuple implements Comparable<SortedTuple> {
        int[] values;

        public SortedTuple(int... values) {
            this.values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
            Arrays.sort(this.values);
        }

        public int size() {
            return values.length;
        }

        public int get(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> asList() {
            // Result type is ArrayList and not the better List,
            // because of the external API of the outer class.
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(values.length);
            for (int value: values)
                list.add(value);
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(values);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            SortedTuple other = (SortedTuple) obj;
            if (!Arrays.equals(values, other.values))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(SortedTuple other) {
            int c = cmp(values.length, other.values.length);
            if (c == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
                    c = cmp(values[i], other.values[i]);
                    if (c != 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(values);
        }

        private static int cmp(int lhs, int rhs) {
            return lhs < rhs ? -1 : lhs > rhs ? 1 : 0; // Cannot overflow like lhs - rhs.
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fourSum(int[] num, int target) {
        final int nTerms = 4;
        SortedTuple values = new SortedTuple(num);
        SortedSet<SortedTuple> results = new TreeSet<SortedTuple>();
        int[] candidateTerms = new int[nTerms];
        int valuesCount = values.size();
        solveNSum(target, nTerms, values, results, candidateTerms, valuesCount);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (SortedTuple solution: results) {
            aList.add(solution.asList());
        }
        return aList;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] num = { 1, 3, 1, 3, 4 };
        final int requiredSum = 4;
        final int nTerms = 2;

        SortedTuple values = new SortedTuple(num);
        SortedSet<SortedTuple> results = new TreeSet<SortedTuple>();
        int[] candidateTerms = new int[nTerms];
        int valuesCount = values.size();
        solveNSum(requiredSum, nTerms, values, results, candidateTerms, valuesCount);

        System.out.println("Solutions:");
        for (SortedTuple solution: results) {
            System.out.println("Solution: " + solution);
        }
        System.out.println("End of solutions.");
    }

    private static void solveNSum(int requiredSum, int nTerms, SortedTuple values, SortedSet<SortedTuple> results, int[] candidateTerms, int valuesCount) {
        if (nTerms <= 0) {
            if (requiredSum == 0)
                results.add(new SortedTuple(candidateTerms));
            return;
        }
        if (valuesCount <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        --valuesCount;
        int candidateTerm = values.get(valuesCount);

        // Try with candidate term:
        candidateTerms[nTerms - 1] = candidateTerm;
        solveNSum(requiredSum - candidateTerm, nTerms - 1, values, results, candidateTerms, valuesCount);

        // Try without candidate term:
        solveNSum(requiredSum, nTerms, values, results, candidateTerms, valuesCount);
    }
}
```

One can prune this further:

- Skip the candidate term if the (nTerms - 1) lowest plus the candidate terms give a too large sum;
- terminate if the candidate term plus the next (nTerms -1) terms are too small.
- terminate if valuesCount < nTerms

Comment: Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c, and d in S such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.

Note:
The requirement said "The solution set must not contain duplicate quadruplets".

Comment: Took the effort to turn my "blabla" on the data structures into executable code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> fourSum(int[] num, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(num);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int i=0;
    while(i<num.length-3){
        int j=i+1;
        while(j<num.length-2){
            int left=j+1, right=num.length-1;
            while(left<right){
                if(num[left]+num[right]==target-num[i]-num[j]){
                    ArrayList<Integer> t=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    t.add(num[i]);
                    t.add(num[j]);
                    t.add(num[left]);
                    t.add(num[right]);
                    res.add(t);
                    left++;
                    right--;
                    while(left<right && num[left]==num[left-1])
                        left++;
                    while(left<right && num[right]==num[right+1])
                        right--;
                }else if(num[left]+num[right]>target-num[i]-num[j])
                    right--;
                else
                    left++;
            }
            j++;
            while(j<num.length-2 && num[j]==num[j-1])
                j++;
        }
        i++;
        while(i<num.length-3 && num[i]==num[i-1])
            i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are often frowned upon here. Please add some description of *why* this answer is correct and what you have changed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

public class FourSum {

```
private static int countFourSum(int[] numbers) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        for (int i = j + 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int front = i + 1, rear = numbers.length - 1;

            while (front < rear) {
                if (numbers[front] + numbers[rear] + numbers[i] + numbers[j] == 0) {
                    System.out.printf(String.format("{%d} : {%d} : {%d} : {%d}  \n", numbers[front], numbers[rear],
                            numbers[j], numbers[i]));
                    front++;
                    rear--;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(numbers[front]) > Math.abs(numbers[rear])) {
                        front++;
                    } else {
                        rear--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -5, -6, 2, 4, -1 };
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(countFourSum(numbers));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your solution may have exceeded the time limit and therefore may have not been able to pass the test cases. Below is the code having the runtime `O(n^3)`. Initially, we sort the array which will help us to find the element either by moving forward or backward depending on the number we are looking for. We then take the first element from the array and perform a three sum on the remaining part leading to find the two sum. Only the `ArrayList` is used. `HashMap` is not required.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if(nums==null|| nums.length<4)
        return result;

    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length-3; i++)
    {
        if(i!=0 && nums[i]==nums[i-1]) continue; //Avoid duplicate elements

        for(int j=i+1; j<nums.length-2; j++)
        {
            if(j!=i+1 && nums[j]==nums[j-1]) continue; //Avoid duplicate elements

            int k=j+1;
            int l=nums.length-1;

            while(k<l)
            {
               if(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[l]<target)
               {
                  k++;
               }
               else if(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[l]>target)
               {
                  l--;
               }
               else
               {
                  List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                  t.add(nums[i]);
                  t.add(nums[j]);
                  t.add(nums[k]);
                  t.add(nums[l]);
                  result.add(t);

                  k++;
                  l--;

                  while( k<l &&nums[l]==nums[l-1] ) l--;
                  while( k<l &&nums[k]==nums[k+1] ) k++;
                }
              }
           }
       }
    return result;
}
```